# Error when downloading a zip from overleaf.com

Tags: online, overleaf

On [overleaf.com](https://www.overleaf.com/), Windows 7 PC, my LaTeX files are compiling with no warnings or errors. The PDF is being created OK also.

I keep getting the following error when I attempt do download as zip:

> Sorry, the export failed. Please try again; note that you may have to make a change to your project first. If this problem persists, please contact us.

First tried, searching on-line for the error text. Drew a blank.

Second searched https://tex.stackexchange.com. Drew a blank.

As the compiler is generating neither errors nor warnings and I have successfully downloaded zip-files up to now, I haven't a scooby where to start looking.

Comment: This seems to be a problem with the overleaf server, I'm not sure that anybody but their administrators can be helpful...

Comment: I would tend to agree with @yo'. If the problem persists, do as the error message say: https://www.overleaf.com/contact

Comment: @Torbjørn T, it does persist but only for one report. Will contact them.

Comment: @yo' nothing else for it. Will do.

Comment: I had added an abstract to the document just before this error started. Wondering if this could have pushed it over some size limit, I checked all my input files and found 3 unused PNG files. I deleted them and the zip downloaded fine. It must have been some sort of size limit issue. I will wait until I hear back from the Overleaf admins to confirm before posting as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorted. It was a file size/timeout issue.

I contacted the administrators as suggested, including a link to the project in question. They increased my timeout limit. That resolved the issue.